# Create an none password SSH key by 1 command line

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, ssh-keys

I want to create the SSH key via a script

Since I am going to set empty password anyway, I'm wondering if there is away that I can an empty password SSH key by 1 command line.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "temp@example.com"


ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "temp@example.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): tmp_rsa        
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in tmp_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in tmp_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:R1SEZr34y/4oBRTK3AieT4b8fw1PDG1kUekTfFuHoDA temp@example.com
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|      . E o*+.=+o|
|     o * B=..+.++|
|      = B++...+ *|
|       = .o .+ + |
|        S .o. o .|
|         o  o=   |
|          .o..o  |
|          ..o.   |
|           oo..  |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

I'm trying to create my `tmp_rsa` file with no password with 1 command line.

Any direction on how to do that will be a huge help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh-keygen` has [options](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen) to specify the passphrase and output file on the command line:

> **-f** filename
>   Specifies the filename of the key file.
>   **-N** new_passphrase
>   Provides the new passphrase.

So:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "temp@example.com" -N '' -f tmp_rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in tmp_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in tmp_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:1S94g+i4SBQeqUwQ7uuEx2ZOfp+z8dR+jFBC4qVRj5Y temp@example.com
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|o.     ..        |
|..   .o o+ .     |
| .. +. *E o .    |
|.o o oo..o.o .   |
| .o o   Soo + .  |
|....   o.. . o   |
|.o* . o o..o     |
|oB ....* .. o    |
| .o...=o. ..     |
+----[SHA256]-----+
$ ls
tmp_rsa     tmp_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Can you teach me 1 more command? write that `tmp_rsa.pub` to the end of `authorized_keys` file ?